# How to add a confirm dialogue to many different buttons at once with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have this HTML...

```
<button class="btn-remove-this">Remove this</button>
<button class="btn-remove-that">Remove that</button>
<button class="btn-remove-some-other-thing">Remove some other thing</button>
<!-- and many more 'Remove ...' buttons -->
```

...and this JavaScript.

```
$(function() {
  $('.btn-remove-this').click(function() {
    functionWhichRemovesThis();
  }
  $('.btn-remove-that').click(function() {
    functionWhichRemovesThat();
  }
  $('.btn-remove-some-other-thing').click(function() {
    functionWhichRemovesSomeOtherThing();
  }
  // and many more click handlers
});
```

Now I would like to prompt the user with a confirm dialogue before removing all those things. Is there a way to do it without adding and calling `confirm` inside every single click handler?

I have on my mind something like adding a single class to all of the different buttons (let's say `btn-remove`) and then adding a single click handler which could look like this:

```
$('.btn-remove').click(function() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this?')) {
    // execute the body of the "more specific" click handler
  } else {
    // prevent the body of the "more specific" click handler from executing
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, you are in a right track. go on.

Comment: Yes, that's the way you need to do. Have a single class and do it.

Comment: yes you are in right way. You can do it.:)

Comment: dont forget .(dot) in here $('btn-remove').click(function() {

Comment: I suppose this question should be titled "how to target the element clicked"?

Comment: As you said, just add a btn-remove class to every button, then you can find which one has been clicked by looking at which other class it has. In your else, just add a e.preventDefult() (without forgeting to add your e param in your function). Keep going !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write different click handler for different button and call common check function will function you want to call has a parameter and on ok click you can call that callback function.

```
    $('.btn-remove-this').click(function() {
      check(functionWhichRemovesThis);  
    });

    $('.btn-remove-that').click(function() {
      check(functionWhichRemovesThat);
    });

    $('.btn-remove-some-other-thing').click(function() {
      check(functionWhichRemovesSomeOtherThing);
    });


 function check(callback){
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this?')) {
        callback();
    } else {
    // prevent the body of the "more specific" click handler from executing
    }
  }
```

This is also a way. So that you dont have to modify your code much.

Comment: Adding/modifying as little code as possible was my goal so I like your solution the most. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `data-*` for it here in your case:

```
<button class="btn-remove" data-func="functionWhichRemovesThis">Remove this</button>
<button class="btn-remove" data-func="functionWhichRemovesThat">Remove that</button>
<button class="btn-remove" data-func="functionWhichRemovesSomeOtherThing">Remove some other thing</button>
```

Now in your js code you can do this:

```
var removeUtil = {
    functionWhichRemovesThis           : function(){},
    functionWhichRemovesThat           : function(){},
    functionWhichRemovesSomeOtherThing : function(){}
};

$('.btn-remove').click(function() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this?')) {
     var removeIt = $(this).data('func');
     removeUtil[removeIt];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how i would do it:

```
<button class="btn-remove btn-remove-some-other-thing">Remove something</button>
<button data-callback="App.remove.that" data-confirmText="Remove that?" class="btn-remove btn-remove-some-other-thing">Remove that</button>
<button data-callback="App.remove.this" data-confirmText="Remove this?" class="btn-remove btn-remove-some-other-thing">Remove this</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var App = {};
    App.remove = {};
    // create an object to define different callbacks, outside of document(ready) so you an access it anywhere else you want.
    App.remove['this'] = {
        'yes': function () {
            console.log('this.yes')
        },
        'no': function () {
            console.log('this.no')
        }
    };
    App.remove['that'] = {
        'yes': function () {
            console.log('that.yes')
        },
        'no': function () {
            console.log('that.no')
        }
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn-remove').click(function () {
            var callback = {};
            if (typeof $(this).attr('data-callback') !== 'undefined') {
                // get the callback object of current button.
                callback = $(this).attr('data-callback').split('.').reduce(function (obj, i) {
                    return App.remove[i];
                }, App.remove);
            }

            var confirmText = 'Are you sure you want to remove this?';
            if (typeof $(this).attr('data-confirmText') !== 'undefined') {
                // set alternate text if needed
                confirmText = $(this).attr('data-confirmText');
            }
            if (confirm(confirmText)) {
                if (callback.hasOwnProperty('yes')) {
                    // do callback if property exists in callback object
                    callback.yes();
                }
            } else {
                if (callback.hasOwnProperty('no')) {
                    // do callback if property exists in callback object
                    callback.no();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```